# Is there a way to authenticate a user (using some local PC info) without going through login page in Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

Scenario: if user is part of X company (tenant), app (hosted in Azure) should be able to skip the login page and authenticate user based on some information (for example Azure AD).

If the user is outside of X company (email@othercompany.com) the same app should print a login page in other to authenticate.

Is is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Choose the template based on requirement from Visual Studio

I have chosen `Asp.net Core Web App`

[image]

[image]

Choose the Tenants and click on finish button.

[image]

Then the required NuGets are installed in the application.

[image]

TenantId and ClientId will be stored in the  `Appsettings.json` file.

[image]

Then it will automatically logins with the windows credentials

[image]

From different machine or outside company will prompt to login or choose another account.

[image]

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that app is .Net framework ~4.8 and that "login page" must not obligate users to pick a microsoft account, it must be any email/pass combination created by the user.

Comment: As the framework is 4.8 for Azure Ad and standard LogIn, please refer this [Azure Ad and Standard Login](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet)